# FFMPEG- Convert video to images

Tags: ffmpeg

how can i convert a video to images using ffmpeg? Example am having a video with total duration 60 seconds. I want images between different set of duration like between 2-6 seconds, then between 15-24 seconds and so on. Is that possible using ffmpeg?

Comment: I'll comment with something relevang to all of the answers. You probably don't want to output in png. Output in jpg. If you want good quality, add `-qscale:v 2` parameter.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use the select filter for a set of custom ranges:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='between(t,2,6)+between(t,15,24)' -vsync 0 out%d.png
```

Comment: Hi. How can i specify the frame rate by which it should extract images? example, i want to extrate 5 frames/second between 2 to 6.

Comment: Use `-vf fps=5,select='between(t,2,6)+between(t,15,24)'`

Comment: Thanks for quick response! This will extract images 'between' mentioned time (2-6). How can i get images 'From' 2-6?

Comment: Also, can i mention multiple duration set with 'ss' filter? `ffmpeg -ss 10 -i video.mp4 -to 12 -copyts -vf fps=1 v2f/out%d.png` this would create images from 10 seconds to 12 seconds. Can i give multiple duration set here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `from`. Only one `ss` can be applied.

Comment: Is it like `between(t,2,6)` will extract images between time interval 2-6 (2 and 6 excluding)?

Comment: I just tested. It is inclusive of 2 and 6 :). One final doubt, will the input file be decoded till it reaches the mentioned time position?Or will it be parsed ,just like in specifying `ss` before input

Comment: Nope, decoded till it reaches first qualifying timecode.

Comment: Why `-vsrync 0`? I read the docs but still don't understand: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html -- It seems the 0 option prevents any frames being dropped due to timestamp issues.

Comment: The image2 muxer, which is used to output image sequences, defaults to CFR. So, when given frames with timestamp differences greater than 1/fps, ffmpeg will duplicate frames to keep CFR. Will happen here between selection of t=6 frame and t=15 frame  `vsync 0` prevents that.

Comment: Output numbers with fixed length : out_%04d.jpg (change "4")

Comment: if using powershell you may get error: `Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'`, and in such case you might need to add additional quotes around -vf argument `ffmpeg -i .\in.mp4 -vf "fps=5,select='between(t,150,600)'" -vsync 0 .\out_%d.png`

Answer (score 139):

Official ffmpeg documentation on this: [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://web.archive.org/web/20210621172103/https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Output one image every second:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1 out%d.png
```

Output one image every minute:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf fps=1/60 thumb%04d.png
```

Output one image every 10 minutes:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf fps=1/600 thumb%04d.png
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we specify duration for which we need images? Like i need images between 2-6 seconds and 13-17 seconds of a 60 sec video, through a single command.

Comment: it is possible to seek input video to some starting position, but I'm not sure that ffmpeg has a filter that can accept ranges. Maybe you'll need to make 2 ffmpeg calls (for 2-6 range and 13-17 range).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use ffmpeg library for python, particularly useful if you don't want to add ffmpeg to your pc environment. Start by installing ffmpeg on conda with:`conda install ffmpeg`
Then you can write a script as bellow:

```py
import ffmpeg
input_file_name = 'input_video.mp4'
(ffmpeg
 .input(input_file_name )
 .filter('fps', fps=10, round = 'up')
 .output("%s-%%04d.jpg"%(input_file_name[:-4]), **{'qscale:v': 3})
 .run())
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the select filter in Gyan's answer (which I use with `eq` rather than `between`), I came across another filter in the manual: [`thumbnail`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#thumbnail)

> Select the most representative frame in a given sequence of
> consecutive frames.
>
> The filter accepts the following options:
>
> - **n**: Set the frames batch size to analyze; in a set of n frames, the filter will pick one of them, and then handle the next batch of n
>   frames until the end. Default is 100.
>
> Since the filter keeps track of the whole frames sequence, a bigger n
> value will result in a higher memory usage, so a high value is not
> recommended.
>
> #### Examples
>
> - Extract one picture each 50 frames:
>
>   ```
>   thumbnail=50
>   ```
> - Complete example of a thumbnail creation with ffmpeg:
>
>   ```
>   ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf thumbnail,scale=300:200 -frames:v 1 out.png
>   ```

Answer (score 2):

This will output every single frame of the video, producing the image sequence:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 out%d.png
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).