# Extract image of every frame of a video using react-native-ffmpeg

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg

I have looked all over the internet to get a way to extract image of everyframe of a video using react-native-ffmpeg. I am making a mobile app and I want to show all per frame images on the video timeline. I want to do this natively on mobile so that I can utilise hardware power of mobile. That is the reason I am looking for react-native-ffmpeg kind of library. Am I in the right direction? This [npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg](https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg) is what I am trying to use. I need to know the command to do the job.

Comment: Hello @EdG, were you able to figure this out, please? I'm stuck, trying to implement something similar to WhatsApp status video trimming feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088222/ffmpeg-convert-video-to-images/40090033

Answer (score 0):

To calculate frame rate of the video follow this link :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/110264/how-to-find-frames-per-second-of-any-video-file

After finding the frame rate, you can extract each frame now, for example :

To extract all frames from a 24 fps movie using ffmpeg :
The `%03d` dictates that the ordinal number of each output image will be formatted using `3` digits.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 24/1 out%03d.jpg
```

another resource :
https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/a9277b2eb4425809066c380fed395ab3

also refer to `.execute()` method in `react-native-ffmpeg`.

Comment: OP seems to want a solution using react native ffmpeg specifically.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden OP can use ```.execute()``` method in react-native-ffmpeg

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Sure. (I assumed OP would know that) - I have edited my answer.