# How to convert video to image in react native

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-native, video

I want to record a 10-second video in react native and cut the video into pictures with 0.1 second intervals. Can react-native-ffmpeg be implemented, or other solutions will work, thanks

Comment: ffmpeg , please revise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088222/ffmpeg-convert-video-to-images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG- Convert video to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088222/ffmpeg-convert-video-to-images)

Comment: I saw the link you provided. Can ffmpeg be used in react native?  Thank you for your answer